# Is there a special ULD to be loaded at the main cargo door?

Tags: cargo

Watching [this video](https://youtu.be/i3UWDsUBvRQ?t=51s), it appears that the hydraulic ram intrudes into the cargo space and would run into the Unit Load Device [(ULD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device) that was stowed there.

Is there a special ULD that is loaded on each flight to clear the ram, or is there enough clearance that any ULD will fit in this spot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the container near the door is the same as the others. The containers [do not fill the entire cabin all the way around](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8402ivGimug), which leaves enough space above for things like the door hydraulics. The containers on the upper cargo area below are all 88" x 125", which corresponds to a standard [LD7 container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device).

[image: 767 Freighter Capacity]

<sup>[Source](http://www.ups.com/aircargo/using/services/services/domestic/svc-aircraft.html)</sup>